# Whatsapp-web.js ~ Error: Authenticating via JSON session is not supported for MultiDevice-enabled WhatsApp accounts

Tags: javascript, nodejs, whatsapp, whatsapp-web

quiero hacer un bot con whatsapp-web.js (https://wwebjs.dev/) para enviar un mensaje a respectivos números telefónicos para ello necesito que se guarde la sesión en un archivo y en caso de que exista recupere el mismo. Adjunto código:

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const fs = require("fs")
const { Client, LegacySessionAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');


// Path donde la sesión va a estar guardada
const SESSION_FILE_PATH = './session.json';

// Cargar sesión en caso de que exista una ya guardada
let sessionData;
if(fs.existsSync(SESSION_FILE_PATH)) {
    sessionData = require(SESSION_FILE_PATH);
}

// Uso de valores guardados
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LegacySessionAuth({
        session: sessionData
    })
});

// Save session values to the file upon successful auth
client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
    sessionData = session;
    fs.writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
});
 

client.initialize();
client.on("qr", qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true} );
})


const send_message = [
    "54123456789",
    "54123456789"
]

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Listo")

    send_message.map(value => {
        const chatId = value +"@c.us"
        message = "Prueba 1"
        client.sendMessage(chatId,message);
})})
```

El caso es que ni bien ejecuto `node index.js` me sale el siguiente error:

> C:\Users\Maynar\Desktop\Automation-ServerErrorMessage\whats-node\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\authStrategies\LegacySessionAuth.js:57
> if(isMD) throw new Error('Authenticating via JSON session is not supported for MultiDevice-enabled WhatsApp accounts.');
> ^

> **Error: Authenticating via JSON session is not supported for MultiDevice-enabled WhatsApp accounts.**
> at LegacySessionAuth.getAuthEventPayload (C:...\Desktop\Automation-ServerErrorMessage\whats-node\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\authStrategies\LegacySessionAuth.js:57:24)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Client.initialize (C:...\Desktop\Automation-ServerErrorMessage\whats-node\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:222:34)

No entiendo que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, si tiene que ver con el tema de multi dispositivos de WhatsApp o que. Si alguien podria ayudarme, desde ya se lo agradecería. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de tener el mismo problema al final la explicación, el código final se vería algo así:

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const fs = require("fs")
const { Client, LegacySessionAuth, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');


// Path donde la sesión va a estar guardada
//NO ES NECESARIO
//const SESSION_FILE_PATH = './session.json';

// Cargar sesión en caso de que exista una ya guardada
//NO ES NECESARIO
//let sessionData;
//if(fs.existsSync(SESSION_FILE_PATH)) {
//    sessionData = require(SESSION_FILE_PATH);
//}

// Uso de valores guardados
// ¡LINEA MODIFICADA!
//const client = new Client({
//    authStrategy: new LegacySessionAuth({
//        session: sessionData
//    })
//});
const client = new Client({
     authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
          clientId: "client-one" //Un identificador(Sugiero que no lo modifiques)
     })
})

// Save session values to the file upon successful auth
client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
    //NO ES NECESARIO PERO SI QUIERES AGREGAS UN console.log
    //sessionData = session;
    //fs.writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), (err) => {
    //    if (err) {
    //        console.error(err);
    //    }
    //});
});
 

client.initialize();
client.on("qr", qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true} );
})


const send_message = [
    "54123456789",
    "54123456789"
]

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Listo")

    send_message.map(value => {
        const chatId = value +"@c.us"
        message = "Prueba 1"
        client.sendMessage(chatId,message);
})})
```

Básicamente he cambiado la autenticación, ahora no se guardará en un archivo JSON, se guardará en una carpeta creada llamada .wwebjs_auth.
La autenticación que implementé se llama LocalAuth, ya no vas a necesitar un SESSION_FILE_PATH.

Link del mensaje: https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1378#issuecomment-1094824852